# How to submit a unity html game to itch?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don’t know if this is the right platform to ask on , but I’m having trouble uploading my unity game to itch. I want it to be a browser playable game, and I have tried uploading the index.html and other folders as a zip as itch says, but when I press play the screen goes blank. Please help.

Comment: 1) Are you making a webgl build? 2) have you tried enabling...`name files as hashes` which insures unique file names between builds.

Comment: I’m not sure what that means, but I solved it by deleting and reinstalling unity. That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: (2) is a webgl player build setting (File -> Build Settings -> Player settings)